# What hook to be used for cancelled booking in WooCommerce Bookings?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-data, woocommerce-bookings

I'm trying to make an SQL query to run upon cancellation of a booking, via a custom plugin, updating custom user meta data.

Here's my code:

```
function wporg_callback() {
    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->query("UPDATE usermeta SET meta_value = 15 WHERE umeta_id = 131");
}

add_action('woocommerce_bookings_cancelled_booking', 'wporg_callback');
```

But It's not working. 
Is there something wrong with the query? Is the right action not being used?

---

**Edit** - I Also tried the following without success:

```
add_action('woocommerce_bookings_cancelled_booking', 'wporg_callback'); 
function wporg_callback( $booking_id ) { 
    // Add/Update custom user meta data 
    update_user_meta( 2, 'download_credits', 17 ); 
}
```

Comment: Ok, in the usermeta table, I'm updating the meta_value to 15, for the row where umeta_id is 131

Comment: Hi, so I'm trying to get this to work from a custom plugin I've built. I've taken your advice and updated my code to the following:add_action('woocommerce_bookings_cancelled_booking', 'wporg_callback');
function wporg_callback( $booking_id ) {

    // Add/Update custom user meta data
    update_user_meta( 2, 'download_credits', 17 );
}

Comment: I am only trying to check if the woocommerce_bookings_cancelled_booking hook is registering for me, and so far it is not working. I've double checked to make sure the arguments for the update_user_meta are correct

Comment: I was replying to someone else's comments, which they deleted.

Comment: Ok, in any case you should probably clarify your question further: what you have done to debug, what "it's not working" means etc.

Comment: I finaly found the correct hook to be used… This time it works fine: I get the correct user Id from the booking and the user custom meta data is saved to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

The correct hook to be used is `woocommerce_booking_cancelled` (a composite hook) that will allow you to retrieve the user ID and to Add/update custom user meta data like below:

```
add_action('woocommerce_booking_cancelled', 'booking_cancelled_transition_to_callback', 10, 2 );
function booking_cancelled_transition_to_callback( $booking_id, $booking ) {
    // Get the user ID from the Booking ID
    $user_id = get_post_field ('post_author', $booking_id);
    
    $download_credits = get_post_meta( $booking_id, '_booking_cost', true );
    
    // Add/Update custom user meta data
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'download_credits', $download_credits );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

---

**How to get the booking data** *(from the booking ID displayed in the order)*:

- Go to your database under `wp_postmeta` table to get the desired `meta_key` from the `post_id` (that is the booking ID)
- Use that **meta key** in `get_post_meta()` WordPress function like:

  ```
   $meta_value = get_post_meta($booking_id, 'the_meta_key', true);
  ```

---

> **Notes:**
>
> - **An SQL query is not needed** to add/update custom user meta data, as you can use instead the dedicated Wordpress function [`update_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/).
> - I couldn't make it work using `woocommerce_bookings_cancelled_booking` hook.

---

[WooCommerce Bookings action and filters hooks developer documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/bookings-action-and-filter-reference/)

Comment: Thankyou, I'm actually using it in my plugin but it still seems to work. Would you happen to know how I can get the booking data, specifically the cost, via the booking id?